# getFeatureInfo issue in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I'm configuring a new server with GeoServer and when I try to do a GetFeatureInfo query gets no feature found. I already check extension, bounds, names... and everything seems to be ok.

Any idea?

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?bbox=-4.01855,36.75382,-4.01833,36.75390&styles=mapama&format=jpeg&info_format=text/plain&request=GetFeatureInfo&layers=sigpac2019:pg_malaga_2019_muni_94&query_layers=sigpac2019%3Apg_malaga_2019_muni_94&width=550&height=250&x=170&y=160

"no features were found"

The query is correct, the bbox are into layer limits.

Comment: This should works, compare and find the differencies. At least you are missing &VERSION=. http://localhost:8080/geoserver/topp/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&QUERY_LAYERS=topp%3Astates&LAYERS=topp%3Astates&exceptions=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&INFO_FORMAT=text%2Fhtml&FEATURE_COUNT=50&X=50&Y=50&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&STYLES=&WIDTH=101&HEIGHT=101&BBOX=-101.3818362057209%2C27.46582058072091%2C-92.5048830807209%2C36.34277370572091. Is your layer a polygon layer so  a click must be inside some feature?

Comment: Yes, the layer is a polygon layer. The query is correct, no logs... So I think its something related to the layer config. But I have no idea what could be...

Comment: what shows up in the debug network console? does the URL work in a browser? if so is it a CORS issue?

Comment: Yes, it works in Chrome with no errors in debug console. The query is working, but the layer or wms or something isn't.

Comment: Have you try to add the SRS to the request?. Is the layer and the request bounds in the same SRS?.